# Firebase saludo de usuario

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-auth, firebase-storage

Hola buenas tardes a la persona que lea esto, estoy teniendo un pequeno problema con desarrollar un saludo  al usuario que ingresa exitosamente a la pagina web.

Lo que estoy viendo es como extraigo los datos de la base
este el el codigo que desarrolle para el registro:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="../stylesheet/styles.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>

    <head>

        <h1> Formulario de registro WEB </h1>

    </head>
    

    
    <body>
            <form >

                <!-- Nombre -->

                <label htmlFor="nameField"> Nombre </label>
                <input type="text" id="nameField" required />
            
                <!-- Apellido -->

                <label htmlFor="lastField"> Apellido </label>
                <input type="lastname" id="lastField" required/>

                <!-- Identificacion del usuario -->
                
                <label htmlFor="idlField"> Numero de identificacion </label>
                <input type="text" id="idField" required/>


                <!-- Nombre de Usuario -->
                
                <label htmlFor="userField"> Nombre de Usuario </label>
                <input type="text" id="userField" required/>

                <!-- Correo -->
                
                <label htmlFor="emailField"> Correo </label>
                <input type="email" id="emailField" required/>

                <!-- Contrasena -->
               
                <label htmlFor="passwordField"> Contrasena </label>
                <input type="password" id="passwordField" required/>

            

            </form>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" id="sighUp" name="signup_submit" value="Registrarse" />
            <A href="./login.html"> Quieres iniciar sesion ?</A>

            <!-- <button name="button" id="button" onclick="guardar()"> Registrar </button> -->

            <script type="module">

                import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.4.0/firebase-app.js";
                import { getDatabase, set, ref, update} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.4.0/firebase-database.js";
                import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword, onAuthStateChanged, signOut } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.4.0/firebase-auth.js";

              <!-- Aqui tengo el Config de firebase pero no lo voy a mostrar -->
                // Initialize Firebase
                const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
                const database = getDatabase(app);
                const auth = getAuth();

               sighUp.addEventListener('click',(e) => {

                var name = document.getElementById("nameField").value;
                var lastname = document.getElementById("lastField").value;
                var id = document.getElementById("idField").value;
                var username = document.getElementById("userField").value;
                var email = document.getElementById("emailField").value;
                var password = document.getElementById("passwordField").value;

                createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
                    .then((userCredential) => {
                    // Signed in 
                    const user = userCredential.user;
                    alert('usuario creado')

                    set(ref(database, 'users/' + user.uid),{
                        name: name,
                        lastname: lastname,
                        id: id,
                        username: username,
                        email: email,
                        
                    })

                    
                    // ...
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                    const errorCode = error.code;
                    const errorMessage = error.message;

                    alert(errorMessage);
                    // ..
                    });


               });

                    












            </script>
    </body>

    <!-- Librerias que vamos a usar -->

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>


    <!-- Nuestros Scripts -->
                                                                
    <script type="module" src="../js/configuracion.js"></script>
   <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/guardar.js"></script> -->


</html>
```

Lo que me gutaria trabajar es que el usuario al acceder a la pagina pueda ser saludado por su nombre de usuario sin problema, pero cuando lo intento no extrae los datos de ningun lado tendria que probar de nuevo a ver que sucede pero no logro codear esa parte